Export content of TextField widget along with its styles as Image in flutter
i am struggling for past 2 days in order to achieve the following:
I have a requirement where TextField has text and the styles are background color, line spacing and font size. I was able to export the content successfully on iOS simulator (did not try android yet). However, when content is long, only the visible part being exported. I have put wrapped the RepaintBoundary with SingleChildScrollView and also TextField with SingleChildScrollView with no luck. see the below code and suggest what can be done to achive the mentioned requirement.
this is my widget
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: RepaintBoundary(
      key: _globalKey,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          // color: backgroundColor,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: backgroundColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                8.0), // Add this line to set the rounded corners
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                children: [
                  CustomPaint(
                    size: Size(
                        double.infinity,
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                            0.9), // Adjust height as needed
                    painter: const NotebookLinePainter(),
                  ),
                  Positioned.fill(
                      child: TextField(
                    controller: myController,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: fontSize,
                      height: lineHeight,
                      color: textColor,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                          .det_hint, //"Insert your message",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                            16.0), // Add this line to set the rounded corners
                      ),
                      contentPadding:
                          const EdgeInsets.all(12), // Add padding
                    ),
                    scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: null,
                    autofocus: true,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                    // controller: myController,

                    onChanged: (value) {
                      // Update the Hive storage
                      // _id = args['id'];
                      // _title = args['title'];
                      currentText = value;
                      _updateNote(value);
                    },
                  ))
                ],
              ),
              // _buildExportableContent(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )

and here is my export to image function
  Future<void> _exportToImage2() async {
try {
  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

  // Ensure the entire widget is laid out
  await Future.delayed(
      Duration(milliseconds: 100)); // Give it a moment to settle

  RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = _globalKey.currentContext!
      .findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;

  // Ensure the widget is painted
  if (boundary.debugNeedsPaint) {
    await Future.delayed(
        Duration(milliseconds: 100)); // Wait until the widget is painted
  }

  // Capture the image
  ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
  ByteData? byteData =
      await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

  if (byteData == null) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Error creating image.')));
    return;
  }

  final Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final imagePath = File('${directory.path}/exported_note.png');
  await imagePath.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);

  final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(pngBytes);
  if (result['isSuccess']) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Image saved to gallery!')));
  }
} catch (e) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to export image: $e')));
}

}
Thank you.

After posting this question, I was able to resolve the issue. I wished that I posted the question earlier :D
I removed the RepaintBoundary from main widget,
I have added text widget which is not visible on screen and the purpose of it only to export it as another child
                  RepaintBoundary(
                key: _globalKey,
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
                  color: backgroundColor,
                  child: Text(
                    myController.text,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: fontSize,
                      height: lineHeight,
                      color: textColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

export function code
  Future<void> _exportToImage3() async {
try {
  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

  // Ensure the entire widget is laid out
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));

  RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = _globalKey.currentContext!
      .findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;

  // Capture the image
  ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 1.0);
  ByteData? byteData =
      await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

  if (byteData == null) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Error creating image.')));
    return;
  }

  final Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final imagePath = File('${directory.path}/exported_note.png');
  await imagePath.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);

  final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(pngBytes);
  if (result['isSuccess']) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Image saved to gallery!')));
  }
} catch (e) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Failed to export image: $e')));
}

}
Edit: Manage the state to make this new Text widget visible and not visible before and after exporting.
